# Returning result from nested anonymous function in a hubot script

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

Having never worked with coffescript before, I'm trying to update the [hubot script for jenkins integration](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/src/scripts/jenkins.coffee). In a nutshell I want to call jenkins, get a result from that call and use it in a subsequent call. Based on the existing code in the hubot script I've added the following function:

```
jenkinsCrumb = (msg) ->
    url = process.env.HUBOT_JENKINS_URL
    path = "#{url}/crumbIssuer/api/json"

    req = msg.http(path)

    if process.env.HUBOT_JENKINS_AUTH
      auth = new Buffer(process.env.HUBOT_JENKINS_AUTH).toString('base64')
      req.headers Authorization: "Basic #{auth}"

    req.get() (err, res, body) ->
        if err
          msg.reply "Jenkins says: #{err}"
        else if 200 <= res.statusCode < 400 # Or, not an error code.
          msg.reply "#{body}"
          body
        else if 404 == res.statusCode
          msg.reply "Unable to fetch crumb from Jenkins..."
        else
          msg.reply "Jenkins says: Status #{res.statusCode} #{body}"
```

When this function is called, the value I want is reported in the variable `body`. The call to `msg.reply` properly displays the value in the hubot chat window.

What I would like to do, but can't figure out, is how to have this function return the value of `body`? I've tried explicitly returning the value of `req.get()` but it seems that it's returning the full request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by simply adding `return body` or just `body` (because of CoffeeScript) to the end of your anonymous function:

```
jenkinsCrumb = (msg, callback) ->
    url = process.env.HUBOT_JENKINS_URL
    path = "#{url}/crumbIssuer/api/json"

    req = msg.http(path)

    if process.env.HUBOT_JENKINS_AUTH
      auth = new Buffer(process.env.HUBOT_JENKINS_AUTH).toString('base64')
      req.headers Authorization: "Basic #{auth}"

    req.get() (err, res, body) ->
        if err
          msg.reply "Jenkins says: #{err}"
        else if 200 <= res.statusCode < 400 # Or, not an error code.
          msg.reply "#{body}"
          body
        else if 404 == res.statusCode
          msg.reply "Unable to fetch crumb from Jenkins..."
        else
          msg.reply "Jenkins says: Status #{res.statusCode} #{body}"

        # critical part
        callback(body)
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out something he's missing: Coffee returns the last value in a block by default. So in his first case it was returning the `req.get` function (I think).

Comment: @jcollum - This appears to be exactly what is happening.  I tried what @ccg suggested but what I'm still getting is apparently a JSON block returned from `req.get()` rather than `body`. So how do I return what's in `body` as opposed to what's returned by `req.get()`?

Comment: if `jenkinsCrumb` needs to return `body` it will need to take in a callback and return the `body` to that callback ( as in `done(body)`); since @ccg already got you 95% of the way there I'll ask him modify his code to accomplish that

Comment: @jcollum I have modified the code to include the callback.